# File not found exception in Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an app to manipulate XML in Windows Phone 8.1 RT. the code is below

```
private void btnXcute_tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    xmlmanipulation();
}

private async void xmlmanipulation()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    try
    {
        var filex = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(@"xmlfile.xml");
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filex);
        var word = xdoc.Descendants("word");
        int max = word.Count();
        txt1.Text = word.FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();
        txt1_Copy.Text = xdoc.Descendants("meaning").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();

        //node removal part
        xdoc.Root.Elements("wordset").Where(dim_word => dim_word.Element("word").Value == word.FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString() && dim_word.Element("meaning").Value == xdoc.Descendants("meaning").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString())
            .FirstOrDefault().Remove();

        //file overwriting part
        var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("xmlfile.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            xdoc.Save(stream);      // Save XDocument into the stream
            stream.Position = 0;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception s) 
    {
        txt1.Text = s.Message;
        txt1_Copy.Text = s.Source;

    }
}
```

I have placed the XML file(xmlfile.xml) in the project main folder as below
[image]

But I get `The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070002)` and the Exception source is `mscorlib`.

I am very new to XML manipulation. Please help me. All I need to read an XML file, remode a the very first `<wordset>` element on it, save the file (overwrite) on a button click. I have total 4 `<wordset>` elements and if I press the button 4 times, all the elements will be removed in the file.

My XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xmlfile>
  <wordset>
    <word>word1</word>
    <meaning>meaning1</meaning>
  </wordset>
  <wordset>
    <word>word2</word>
    <meaning>meaning2</meaning>
  </wordset>
  <wordset>
    <word>word3</word>
    <meaning>meaning3</meaning>
  </wordset>
  <wordset>
    <word>word4</word>
    <meaning>meaning4</meaning>
  </wordset>
</xmlfile>
```

Comment: Have you set the file property "Copy to output" to "Always"?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel yes, but still no luck.

Comment: try this 


XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("ms-appx:///xmlfile.xml");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access file from *Installed location* not *LocalFolder* (depending on file's build action). Therefore you should use:

```
var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
// not:
var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

You can also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24339587/2681948).