# Read XML file in Windows Phone 8.1 Background task

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am building a Windows Phone 8.1 RT App which runs MP3 files in **Background task**.

I followed the steps in the sample code shown here : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319

In MyPlaylistManager Project I would like to build my own Playlist from XML file.

When I try to access this XML file I am getting an exception.

> An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in SYSTEM.XML.NI.DLL but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An internal error has occurred.

I have added the XML file to the Project and set

> Build Action : Content
>
> Copy to Output Directory : Copy if newer

To access the file I tired below options :

```
  XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("ms-appx:///XYZ.xml");

  XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("XYZ.xml");
```

XDocument.Load is supported in Windows Phone 8.1 as per the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181(v=vs.110).aspx

[image: Directory Structure of my Solution]

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Remember that I am trying to do this in a background task

Comment: DOes it work when you deserialize it in the foreground process? Can you also check if the file exists and maybe its content - `StorageFile file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("XYZ.xml");`?

Comment: I tried your code but to check if file exists : An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code. You r right, its not able to find the file.

Comment: @Romasz When I try GetFileAsync("ms-appx:///XYZ.xml"); I get An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is, because you aren't providing the correct path. Your file is in project *MyPlaylistManager*. Try to use:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("ms-appx:///MyPlaylistManager/Quran.xml");
// or like this:
StorageFile file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"MyPlaylistManager\Quran.xml");
```

Also not forget to include *MyPlaylistManager* in references. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24339587/2681948) will also help a little.

*EDIT* - you may also try to use [XDocument.Load(Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc838349(v=vs.100).aspx) - then in your *BackgroundTask* first get the *StorageFile* then load *XDocument* using *Stream* got from the file.

Comment: Now I get the file when I use StorageFile file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"SampleBackgroundAudio.MyPlaylistManager\Quran.xml"); had to give Namespace also.

Comment: @SaqibVaid Now, once you get the file, you should be able to process it. Of course there is a chance that there can be other problems.

Comment: But When I try XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("ms-appx:///SampleBackgroundAudio.MyPlaylistManager/Quran.xml"); it throws an error "An internal error has occurred."

Comment: Is this because XML file is corrupted or when I am using ms-appx the file path must be specified in a certain way...

Comment: @SaqibVaid First of all do everyting in foreground process, then when it's working move it to the background task. I'm not sure what can be a problem. You may try get storagefile, then `XDocument.Load(fileStream)` - to see if that works.

Comment: Accessing the file & XDocument.Load works fine when I do it in the foreground process.

Comment: But in the Background process I can read the file but XDocument.Load fails. Not sure why !

Comment: Doing XDocument.Load from Stream Works in Background as well. StorageFile storageFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"SampleBackgroundAudio.MyPlaylistManager\Quran.xml");
            var randomAccessStream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync();
            Stream stream = randomAccessStream.AsStreamForRead();     XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(stream); //WORKS !!!

Comment: Can you update your answer with this so I can Mark It as Answer.

Comment: @SaqibVaid I've updated the answer. Glad that this works, thought I'm not still sure why URI version hadn't worked.