# How Background task access Main app JSON file

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have created background task in similar fashion as mentioned in below link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj991805.aspx

Live tile is working fine with above code.

Problem :
In above link. we are extracting feed from MSDN Blog but in my application, I want to access JSON file defined in my app. So overall, I want my background task to access my main app JSON file.

Can you please guide me how background task can access main app JSON file?

Comment: What do you mean by accesing the main app file - file is in LocalFolder, is loaded with the package or is somewhere else? Have you tried [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24339587/2681948)?