# How to include resources to application for windows phone?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem: I created new c# project for windows phone (in VS 2013) and set test file property as "Copy if newer", but I cannot see file in emulator's Local folder. What do I do wrong?

More detailed:

1. Create app:
   `File->New->Project->Templates->Visual C#->Store Apps->Windows Phone Apps->Blank App (Windows Phone)`
2. set test file property
   [image: TestText.txt isn't empty]
3. run on emulator (there is a button for this) and list files with code:

   ```cs
   async void listFolder()
   {
       StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
       Stack<StorageFolder> stack = new Stack<StorageFolder>();
       stack.Push(local);

       StorageFolder current;
       string path;
       byte[] bytes;
       StorageFile logFile = await local.CreateFileAsync("log.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
       using (var s = await logFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
       {
           while (stack.Count > 0)
           {
               current = stack.Pop();
               foreach (StorageFolder f in await current.GetFoldersAsync())
               {
                   stack.Push(f);
               }
               path = current.Path;
               bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(current.Path + "\n");
               s.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
               foreach (StorageFile f in await current.GetFilesAsync())
               {
                   bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(f.Path + "\n");
                   s.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
               }
               s.Flush();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Check file with Windows Phone Power Tools. Local folder contains log.txt only. Log contains Local directory and log file. No TestText.txt

How do I include file to application and access it on emulator?

Limitations:
I do need to held data on local storage (no web links, no cloud)

Comment: You need to read the file from package  not local folder - it's not the same. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24339587/2681948) should help. Also remember that *Package* is *read-only* - so you will be able to get files from it but not write them.

Comment: @Romasz Thanks for comment! I would accept it if you turn it into an answer.

Comment: No problem. I've turned it into answer as it may be easier to find that the one from the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access files that come with your package, then you need to use [Package.InstalledLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation), you won't find those files in [ApplicationData.LocalFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder).

Note that files included in *Package* are *read-only* and you won't be able to write them.

Some more information you will also find [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24339587/2681948).